# ZigZag line in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a ZigZag line in Java using chars but the code isn't working

```
public void ZigZag(int width, int height, boolean infinite, char ch){
    System.out.println(ch);
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < width; ++i)
            printline(i);
        for (int i = width - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            printline(i);
    }
}

void printline(int i, char ch) {
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println(ch);
}
```

P.S The user inputs the char and the program makes zigzag using that char

[image: Pic]

Comment: Can you tell us what you're passing into the `ZigZag(...)` method?  What the expected output should be and what output you're actually getting?

Comment: Could you give us code which actually compiles. You call `printline` with one argument, while it takes two arguments

Comment: I can't because i don't know whats the mistake in the code thats why i posted here.

Comment: `printline(int i, char ch)` You are saying that `printline` needs an int and a char, but you are only giving it an int `printline(i);`. My guess is you want `printline(i, ch);` Also, if your code doesn't compile you should post the error message you are getting.

Comment: I want the input from the user (ex char = '/') and the programs makes zigzag using that char

Comment: @Takendarkk Thanks a lot it's working now
Make it as an answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling your method correctly. Your method's signature is

```
void printline(int i, char ch)
```

which means you must pass it an int **and** a char. Right now you are only calling it with an int. Change

```
printline(i);
```

to

```
printline(i, ch);
```